# Watching new tags on GitHub

Tags: github

I need to track new tags of many projects on github, it's possbile to get emails about newly created tags? Or through RSS channel, or somehow be notified, when new tag is created.
I think that this would be great feature how to track new versions of projects hosted on github.

Comment: Here is a discussion you can vote for: `'Tags' events notifications in watching settings` : https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/4784

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> I need to track new tags of many projects on github [...] through RSS channel

GitHub provides an atom feed for tags

- **Syntax:** `https://github.com/{:user}/{:repository}/tags.atom`
- **Example:** ***https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/tags.atom*** will list the **[tags of the LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/tags)** project

Answer (score 7):

Update Nov. 2020: you now have "[Custom notification controls](https://github.blog/2020-11-20-whatcha-watchin-custom-notification-controls/)"

> This week we are giving you more control over the types of content that you are notified about on GitHub:
>
> [image: Watching gets granular]
>
> Watching a repository can often be a double-edged sword.
> You want to stay up to date with a project, but if you have a specific interest or role within the community, you have no choice but to subscribe to updates on everything.
> No more.
>
> Beneath the watch button, you’ll find that we have made a few changes: we’ve made the language clearer so you know what you’ll receive updates about, we’ve made the interface more accessible and, we’ve introduced a new custom category.
> Within this, you can select the types of content you would like to be notified about.
>
> Do you focus on code review? Limit your notifications to pull requests.
> Are you a community manager? Select Discussions.
> As new types of notifications are added, you’ll find them in this menu.
>
> You’ll find these controls on all repository pages and on your watching page where you can customize notifications for repositories you already watch.

---

Since you can have [email notifications](https://help.github.com/articles/about-email-notifications/), do note that, since Nov. 2018, you can get notification on new releases: that won't include *all* tags (since a release is associated to a tag, but not all tags receive a release).

Still, see "[Watch releases](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-11-27-watch-releases/) "

> You can now limit repository notifications exclusively to releases.
> Receive notifications when new releases are published in a repository without receiving notifications about other updates and conversations.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/notifications/watch-releases.png]

Comment: What about notifications for a tag creation which does not have a release (or no releases at all)? The Releases nor Discussion 
(both are enabled) seems does not work for that. I know at least one project which makes release outside of the github, but does store the sources and make tags for a related release publicated outside.

Comment: @Andry Then you would need a GitHub Action on `create` event: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#create

Comment: It said `Runs your workflow when someone creates a Git reference (Git branch or tag) in the workflow's repository.`. It's not mine repository, I want to track someone's else repository.

Comment: @Andry Sorry, I misinterpreted your first comment. A GitHub Action could still do the trick, associated to a dummy repository of yours, through a [schedule event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule), and you can [checkout another (public) repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889190/6309) from said GitHub Action.

Comment: Not sure how a checkout of any repository does trigger the notification. But I've tested comitting from the GitHub Actions and it does not trigger the notifications. May be some Rest API could do the trick, but couldn't find any.

Comment: @Andry The idea behind a scheduled event is to *not* wait for a notification to be triggered, but to regularly (on schedule) inspect a remote repository by fetching it (through a checkout) and inspecting its tags: any new tag can then be reported.

Comment: The problem with the "reported", there is no any API I could find. Yes I can recommit it to mine repository, but this is not a GitHub notification.

Comment: @Andry Yes, I didn't know exactly what you need when detecting a new commit (from your initial "I want to track someone's else repository"), sending a notification to a slack channel? Updating an issue in your project? Sending an email? ...

Comment: Just as usual a GitHub in page notification in upper right corner, just like in this answer.

Comment: @Andry Right. Not sure if this is supported indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at https://sibbell.com

It notifies you about new tags/releases and takes only 3 clicks to setup.

Really handy tool.

Comment: It does redirect to `dependencies.io` with a trial and without free plans.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a simple tool, because Sibbell will be closing down on May 15th, 2018, as they told on their email yesterday.

I've put together a simple repository to have the same approach:

https://github.com/Ardakilic/alerthub

You can self-host it. Just provide your repositories and when a new release comes you'll get a push notification (using Pushbullet) and/or E-mail. You can also have an aggregated RSS feed to use with your reader app or IFTTT etc.

Comment: Thx @Arda looks really usable and clean.

Comment: Thanks @SilverZachara , I'm glad you liked it :) This is my first NodeJS project which I've open sourced, so any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://AllMyChanges.com.

It is a startup which could do more — it will send you a full release notes, not only new version numbers. And it works for projects without any release notes as well as with projects were maintainers keep handwritten ChangeLog.

Comment: Looks like they've gone out of business.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/111#issuecomment-442564269

> It appears that "watch releases only" doesn't follow tags and many projects use only tags for announcing new versions. While https://newreleases.io/ sends notifications for tags too, it also has several version filtering options, based on regex expressions, pre and updated releases. It also offers email frequency options.

Related issue to up vote: `Ability to subscribe to tags (not releases)` : https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/399

`https://newreleases.io/`:

**Pros**:

- Can track tags
- Can send notifications to a Telegram account
- An alternative way of the watch if you been blocked: https://docs.github.com/en/communities/maintaining-your-safety-on-github/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account

**Cons**:

- Can not track assets update only: https://github.com/newreleasesio/client-go/issues/7