# Notifications for new Github project releases?

Tags: github

I'm using a library from a Github project. Is there some way to set up a notification for new project releases?

For example, I want to know when a new release appears [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/releases)

I know I can be notified on every issue update, but that's not what I'm looking for. Though I see [some projects](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/BindingCalculator/issues/1) are using that as a way to keep people notified

Comment: This is the same as asking for an email when a friend updates their Facebook status. Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it has nothing to do with coding) or direct to GitHub:Support.

Comment: @random This is related to coding since I need to track updates to all the libraries I depend on

Comment: I would vote to reopen, but then it's a close duplicate of this older question with (IMO) better answers: [Watching new tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18685796/476716)

Comment: I think [Octobox](https://octobox.io/) or [HubNotify](https://hubnotify.com/) can do this.

Comment: https://sibbell.com can do this

Comment: I've built such a tool: https://releases.netlify.com/

Comment: I've made a self-hosted tool especially for this: https://github.com/Ardakilic/alerthub You can get notified by email or via push notification using pushbullet.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Don't know about email, but you can subscribe to <strike>RSS</strike> Atom feed with releases:
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/releases.atom
or tags:
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/tags.atom

---

**EDIT**:

To get notification via email you can use [Sibbell.com](https://sibbell.com) or RSS-to-email service like [Blogtrottr](http://blogtrottr.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't looking for email in particular anyway (updated question)

Comment: +1. Note that it works because a GitHub release is obligatory to be linked to a tag.

Comment: Maybe this is a recent feature, but https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/releases.atom is a release specific feed.

Comment: To get notified you can use iftt.com. Basically add a recipe that will send you an email whenever there's a new item found in the rss/atom feeds.

Comment: You can get emails for Github releases from sibbell.com - see http://www.davegaeddert.com/2014/10/11/sibbell-emails-for-new-releases-on-github/

Comment: And also you can setup emails when .atom feed changes via IFTTT.

Comment: Many thanks for this; saves me a huge amount of work in checking feeds. Glad I finally got fed up with checking for new releases.

Comment: @DmitrySemenov Cheers for the tip. Spent 10 minutes setting up my fave repos and it already sent me a few mails (e.g. Bootstrap-UI release 12.1). Great stuff.

Comment: As @Stuart suggested, sibbell.com is a must. Very useful and elegant.

Comment: Also, if you use [Slack](https://slack.com) you can use RSS integration to subscribe releases with atom feed above. You can type `/feed help` on any slack channel to see subscription options.

Comment: Sibbell now appears to cost money to subscribe to releases. [BlogTrottr](http://blogtrottr.com/) is a simple RSS-to-email service that's ad-supported.

Comment: Sibbell is down right now, but something is up https://github.com/sibbell/sibbell-issues/issues/60

Comment: I changed from Blogtrottr to Inoreader, they can also send mail when a new entry is added to the RSS feed. Inoreader sends an ad-free mail, unlike Blogtrottr.

Comment: This is free and to email: https://libraries.io/ TOP!

Comment: libraries.io looks good, but it can't send notifications for GitHub tags/releases yet: https://github.com/librariesio/libraries.io/issues/127

Comment: You can add the RSS feed to Outlook.  I just did for another GitHub project, so I'll be notified when Release Notes are updated... thanks @JorritSchippers for the link.  **`https://github.com/`** *`username/projectname`* **`/releases.atom`**

Comment: sibbell.com is sunsetting as of May 15, 2018

Comment: For those who are wary of using a free service that could be sunsetted like Sibbel was, I wrote a comprehensive guide on setting this up using AWS Lambda's free tier: https://www.tonylykke.com/posts/subscribing-to-project-releases-with-lambda/

Comment: I know, thats a really old question. But maybe someone finds this. Sibbell is down and there are many alternatives fore. As for now https://release-notifier.com/ worked for me the best.

Answer (score 57):

### Github

Github now allows it natively

Go to a project page and click Watch button in the top right corner. There's a `Custom` option where you can toggle `Releases`.

[image: Watch]

### NewReleases.io

https://newreleases.io/

This app sends you emails and also can slack into specified channel.

[image]

### GitPunch.com

https://gitpunch.com/

1. You pick a repository/ies:
   [image]
2. Then setup your notification preferences:
   [![enter image description here][4]][4]

Notifications start coming to your email

Comment: NewReleases.io looks nice, but it cannot monitor your GitHub account for new stars, can it?

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to **sign up for auto notifications** via:

- https://newreleases.io/ ([thx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350626/139040))
- https://release-notifier.com
- https://libraries.io
- https://gitpunch.com ([currently not sending emails](https://github.com/vfeskov/gitpunch/issues/175))
- https://coderelease.io ([currently not sending emails](https://github.com/CodeRelease/CodeRelease/issues/18))
- https://releases.netlify.com (does not send emails)

Setup a job to **call a webhook**:

- https://github.com/justwatchcom/github-releases-notifier
- https://github.com/femtopixel/github-release-notifier

Or if you would like to **get a notification when the atom feed is updated**, you can use these (in addition to the ones indicated by Mikalai): https://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/Be-notified-when-a-new-release-is-created-in-a-GitHub-repository

Comment: Another alternative: https://releases.netlify.com

Comment: @KirillGroshkov added, thanks

Comment: Wow, just tried all of them and more. GitPunch and CodeRelease do not send emails (https://github.com/vfeskov/gitpunch/issues/175, https://github.com/CodeRelease/CodeRelease/issues/18). releaser.richardhagen.no does not open. releases.netlify.com does not send emails. hubnotify.com is 404.

Comment: Thx for the headsup, @bers ! I will update

Comment: Another project: https://release-notifier.com

Answer (score 1):

I made a [Ver.bot](https://rping.github.io/Ver.bot-site), which can send **GitHub** projects notifications about new version release. Besides GitHub projects, you can also subscribe **npm**, **PyPI** projects. The bot is currently on Slack, Telegram and Skype.

Comment: See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212). In particular, at least acknowledge that you're linking to your own work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [rss2email](https://github.com/wking/rss2email). You can set it up and run it on every OS with python installed.

Answer (score 0):

Touchpine monitors open source projects and will notify you when there are new releases.   If the project you want to follow isn't already monitored, you can request it be added.

https://touchpine.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party I know, but Axibase has a nice little tool to leverage GitHub's webhook functionality to notify you via some third-party messenger service (or email if you so choose) whenever someone creates a new project in one of your repositories.

[image: Notification Workflow]

The workflow above describes the underlying process, and this [guide](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/github/project-release-notification.html) will walk you through the set-up step by step. The entire process takes around 10 minutes to complete.

Disclaimer: I've worked for the team that developed ATSD, which is the database used for these notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is very old but I found this:

http://coderelease.io