# How do I use Github actions to checkout a different public repo, then add some files from this repo to it, then build etc

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to work out how to use Github Actions to checkout a remote public repo, then add some some sensitive files into it from the current repo, before finally building etc.

I believe I can checkout a remote repo with

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      repository: foo-user/bar-repo
```

But how do I then copy some files into this checked out repo from files that are in the current repo?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have a couple options:

Checkout your repo and then checkout the public repo:

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      repository: foo-user/bar-repo
      path: './bar'
```

Now you can go ahead and copy files from the folder `bar` into whereever else you want

---

The other option is to have the public repo as a submodule, then you can simply do:

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      submodules: true
```

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. How would I then copy from one to the other. What paths do I use? Sorry, github actions noob here.

Comment: @SystemicPlural in both cases, your pwd will be the root of your github repo, and the public repo will be inside this folder. So you can do `cp ./bar/file .` to copy `file` from bar into your repo directory

Comment: Does `path` have to be relative?