# GitHub Actions: Copy a file from a repo to my own

Tags: github-actions

I want to copy one particular file from another GitHub repo to my own GitHub repo (both are public repos). How do I do this?

Comment: Copy it simply using ctrl + c

Comment: I want to automate it since that file is often updated and I use it in my repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Github actions to checkout a different public repo, then add some files from this repo to it, then build etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889035/how-do-i-use-github-actions-to-checkout-a-different-public-repo-then-add-some-f)

Comment: @Mushroomator The person is talking about the opposite of what I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you could use the [`curl Action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-curl) to download the file and then push the file to the repository like described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921401/push-to-origin-from-github-action/58393457#58393457).

Another option is described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889035/how-do-i-use-github-actions-to-checkout-a-different-public-repo-then-add-some-f?rq=1).